# CSS page break control, how to avoid table row widows (single rows on next page)

Tags: html, css

I have a to print potentially long dynamic tables of varying lenght. Those tables are likely to span over multiple pages. Sometimes, one single row is printed to the next page. I want to avoid that for esthetic reasons.

So this I want:
[image]

To be clear, I do not ask about how to avoid page-breaks inside table-cells or table-rows. This would be easy.

I am (somewhat) familiar with page-break-after, page-break-before, page-break-inside. Still I don't get that done.

Here some fiddler to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/jobe451/Lxb37ejr/10/

The raw result of that fiddler for printing:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jobe451/Lxb37ejr/10/show/

My best unsuccessful try so far was this HTML:

```
      <tr class="row">
          <td class="colLeft">left</td><td class="colRight">right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row afterAvoid">
          <td class="colLeft">left</td><td class="colRight">right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row afterAvoid beforeAvoid">
          <td class="colLeft">left</td><td class="colRight">right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row afterAvoid beforeAvoid">
          <td class="colLeft afterAvoid">left</td><td class="colRight afterAvoid">right</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="row beforeAvoid">
          <td class="colLeft beforeAvoid">left</td><td class="colRight beforeAvoid">right</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

With this CSS:

```
body {
    widows: 3;
    orphans: 3;
}
.afterAvoid {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}
.beforeAvoid {
    page-break-before: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Which browser? Don't see the bug in latest Chrome on OS X. But it works not the same as on your screenshot.

Comment: You could try detecting if it the page break will cut off a row and then insert a page break a few rows before so 2-3 rows will be broken off and it won't look as bad...

Comment: @SergeyDenisov I use Chrome 44 on Windows 7 and Ubuntu. Both share the same issue. The result-link I provided above sometimes has a problem. Sometimes Fiddler adds a top menu to it and puts the content into an iframe. In that case, the print preview doesn't work as it should. I have to open the link sometimes a few times in a few tabs... Sorry don't know how to do that better.

Comment: @Developer_ACE I don't think I can calculate where the page break will be. In my actual real-life problem, I have a various lenght rather complex content before that table. I can't predict where on the page the table will start.

Comment: Okay... Just an idea. You could also force a page break ....